# How can I use the same fields for two different forms?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I'm trying to combine the login and register forms on a WooCommerce/WordPress site. The idea is that a single set of fields, username and password, could be submitted by two different forms. The first way I thought of is (simplified for clarity):

```
<form id="login">
    <input id="username">
    <input id="password">
    <button type="submit">LOG IN</button>
</form>
<form id="register">
    <div style="visibility:hidden!important;position:fixed!important;">
        <input id="register_username">
        <input id="register_password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

Basically, the layout hides the second pair of inputs but shows both buttons. Then, there's some JS that mirrors the values of corresponding fields:

```
var u = $('#username');
var p = $('#password');
var ru = $('#register_username');
var rp = $('#register_password')

$('#login').on('change blur focus click keyup',function(){
    ru.val(u.val());
    rp.val(p.val());
});
```

This seems to trigger a warning that an "invalid field is not focusable" - which I understand - but, can this be solved and done well? Is there a way to do this without JavaScript? Is there a better way altogether?

*Let's assume I will show the hidden stuff in the case that there is no JS on the user's browser. Let's also assume I was given this design and asked to implement it, i.e. this is not a question about UX*.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to create one form with 2 buttons "login" & "Registration"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just merge 2 forms into one and set 2 buttons

```
<form id="login">
    <input id="username">
    <input id="password">
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="login">LOG IN</button>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="registration">REGISTER</button>
</form>
```

After submitting your form you need to check submit value like

```
if($_POST['submit'] == 'login')
    then do code for login
else if($_POST['submit'] == 'registration')
    then do code for registration
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Conveniently, HTML5 spec says that the default button (ie, what the Enter key usually triggers) is whichever comes first in the markup. I did have to set an additional variable before executing the login code, but this is absolutely the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

To reveal the hidden fields in the case of no javascript you would put the data between the following tags:

As far as the fields that are active when there is JavaScript, place that data within the JavaScript itself using document.write("fields here");.

The end result will be that these fields appear when JavaScript is enabled, and do not appear when JavaScript is disabled.

Hope this helps.